# Catch exceptions while making web api calls

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, api, http

I am making a lot of web api calls in my c# code. I don't know how to catch errors. Suppose, internet connection isn't working, then my code shows runtime error. How to I properly put them into try catch block, What's the general rule. All the articles I found were on how to throw back the error and error message.
example API calls:

```
 WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();
 string res = webResponse.ToString();
```

Also

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
      client.BaseAddress = new Uri(CairoBaseUrl);
      var getStringTask = client.GetStringAsync(requestUrl);
      response = await getStringTask;
```

And,

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(
                url,requestContent);
```

Comment: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/exception-handling

Comment: What don't you understand? Just make a `catch` block, and figure out how you want to handle the error.

Comment: @AnkushJain Can you give one small example on how to handle error in any one of the above snippets

Comment: @SLaks I am new to c#. Don't know exactly how to create try catch block with Httpexceptions

Comment: HttpException is still Exception, you can write 

    try
    {
        // async code with await here
    }
    catch (HttpException e)
    {
        // handle e
    }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you are calling asp.net web api i would suggest you to use HttpClient which is done for that purposes

```
 try    
  {
     HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://www.contoso.com/");
     response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
     string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
     // Above three lines can be replaced with new helper method below 
     // string responseBody = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);

     Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
  }  
  catch(HttpRequestException e)
  {
     Console.WriteLine("\nException Caught!");  
     Console.WriteLine("Message :{0} ",e.Message);
  }
```

This is example from MSDN how to deal with exceptions using http client

in you example you have

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
      client.BaseAddress = new Uri(CairoBaseUrl);
      var getStringTask = client.GetStringAsync(requestUrl);
      response = await getStringTask;
```

But it wont work since await operator can be used only with methods marked async so it should be

```
  var getStringTask = await client.GetStringAsync(requestUrl);
```

Comment: Strongly suggest you not use `e.Message` if you really want the details. Use `e.ToString()`.

Comment: error handling with good patterns for Minimal apis ? check status code?